# Google test error: '*' can only follow a repeatable token

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

Trying to create some unit tests with EXPECT_EXIT where the error message contains a '*'.
The test fails but not with expected error. **What am I missing here?**

Here a very simple example to reproduce the issue:

```
void test_Death() {
    std::cerr << "*Error\n";
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

TEST(ErrorWithStar, Star) {
    EXPECT_EXIT(test_Death(), testing::ExitedWithCode(EXIT_FAILURE), "*Error\n");
}
```

### The result is:

Message:

```
#1 - Failed
Syntax error at index 0 in simple regular expression "*Error
": '*' can only follow a repeatable token.
Running main() from c:\a\1\s\thirdparty\googletest\googletest\src\gtest_main.cc
#2 - Death test: test_Death()
    Result: died but not with expected error.
  Expected: *Error

Actual msg:
[  DEATH   ] *Error
[  DEATH   ]
```

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.11.13.
I added a Google Test project to my solution, created all links etc. It is working perfectly for everything else, but not for messages containing a '*'.

What is meant by "'*' can only follow a repeatable token."?

Comment: I don't know the google test framework, but the error message indicates the string is a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). As such, the character should be escaped: `"\\*Error\n"`

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/5vvPYf43o

Comment: Thanks guys. My bad that I wasn't able to understand the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character `*` is reserved by the [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) grammar to indicate matching zero or more of the previous tokens or groups.

Some simple examples:

- `.*` matches zero or more of *any* character
- `a*` matches zero or more of the character `a`
- `[A-F]*` matches zero or more of the characters `A` through to `F`

The error is occurring because you have a `*` at the beginning of the string, where there is no preceding character, group *etc* to be repeated. This is essentially a syntax error in the regular expression grammar, and the error message tells you so.

What you actually want is a *literal* `*`, not the one that belongs to the grammar. To achieve this, you must escape it with a `\`. And because strings in C++ also use that for an escape character, you must escape the backslash too. So you need two backslashes before the `*` (or use a [raw string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)).

In a pinch, the solution should be:

```
EXPECT_EXIT(test_Death(), testing::ExitedWithCode(EXIT_FAILURE), "\\*Error\n");
```